# Oracle OUD - Docker Container - Add custom objectClass with custom attributes

Tags: oracle, docker, ldap, containers

I have docker container inside docker-compose:

```
      oud:
        image: ****
        container_name: oud
        ports:
          - 1389:1389
        environment:
          - OUD_INSTANCE_NAME=OUD_LOCAL
          - rootUserDN=cn=admin
          - rootUserPassword=admin
          - baseDN=o=uzytkownicy
          - ldifFile_1=/u01/oracle/user_projects/config/oud_local.ldif
        volumes:
          - ./docker/infra/oud/config:/u01/oracle/user_projects/config
```

I try to add the custom objectclass with custom attributes in my oud_local.ldif file, but it doesn't work.

What did I add (example from Oracle docs):

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.1.1.590
  NAME ( 'blog' 'blogURL' )
  DESC 'URL to a personal weblog'
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE
  X-ORIGIN 'Oracle Unified Directory Server'
  USAGE userApplications )

dn: o=uzytkownicy
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
o: uzytkownicy

dn: o=grupy,o=uzytkownicy
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
o: grupy

... and more
```

Just first block crashes. I can create entries but not an custom objectClass.
Actually I want to have copy of remote test server schema localy in my container because I need it to development.

I tried to export ApacheDS schema .ldif from test and tried to load it in container but every object (about ~2100) got rejected.

Can somebody tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it by add schemaConfigFile_1 attribute in docker compose:

```
oud:
image: harbor.nekken.pl/oracle/middleware/oud:12.2.1.4.0
container_name: oud
ports:
  - 1389:1389
environment:
  - OUD_INSTANCE_NAME=OUD_LOCAL
  - rootUserDN=cn=admin
  - rootUserPassword=admin
  - baseDN=o=uzytkownicy
  - schemaConfigFile_1=/u01/oracle/user_projects/config/schema/schema.ldif
```